# img not showing using Thymeleaf and Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf along with springboot

I am not able to view any images in my HTML file. I have tried all different ways of doing the same in thymeleaf but no luck.

Here is my project folder structure

```
 src
└───  main
    └───  resources
        ├───  templates
        ├───  css
        └───  images
```

HTML File

```html
<head>
    <title>Community Bike Share Web Application</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css}" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<div>
    <img th:src="@{/images/taiwan_Bicycle_Ride_hd_wallpaper_8.jpg}"
         src="../images/taiwan_Bicycle_Ride_hd_wallpaper_8.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With Boot's default configuration, your images (and other static content), need to be beneath `src/main/resources/static`. For example, to serve content from `/images` put the files in `src/main/resources/static/images`

Comment: Thanks it now worked. But, I had to make that static folder manually, as I was getting invalid identifier name for creating package name as "static" from STS.

Comment: and how the path will be for `<img src=" ">` after adding image to `src/main/resources/static/IMG.jpg` ? will it be `../../../resources/static/IMG.jpg ?`

Answer (score 0):

This may help. I am using it in my application and no error shown (at least in Mozilla).
use ../.. to access files and directories in your application.

```html
<img alt="Caption X" class="rounded-circle img-responsive mt-2"
   height="128" th:src="@{/../static/images/theImage.png}" width="128">
```

I works fine in Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0):

As Andy Wilkinson said -
With Boot's default configuration, your images (and other static content), need to be beneath `src/main/resources/static`. For example, to serve content from `/images` put the files in `src/main/resources/static/images`

And use it in this way

```
<img th:src="@{/images/image.png}" alt="image" width="300" height="200">
```